# Share database [core data] between different devices, not just the user's ones

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

What is the best way, to share a database between different devices, that are not just the user’s ones, but for example could be his friend’s phone. That means that iCloud is not an option.

Example:  All of my data is app-user specific, so basically:

- user logs into my app, do some work
- then he can log in with the same acc on his friend phone and data should be the same

Is there an any way to upload the whole user specific database to some online storage provider (like firebase,… ) and then download it on another device and initialise core data stack, when the same user logs in on a different device?

Or is it the only way to sync data with the server and than preload the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply upload the whole database file(s) and then download it on another device. The problem though is portability. You need to ensure that both devices support the same version of the database so they are compatible. To port the same thing to another platform is again a different story but doable when not using core data.

Then there is a problem of conflicts. Imagine you forget to log out from the second device and you open it after a week and the database is accidentally synced back to the server. This will make you lose all the data you created on your "main" device.

So in general it is possible to sync the whole thing but you will have loads of issues. You should create a server that supports all entities and works through ids (so you know the object was modified and not created) and date modified to be able to resolve conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

Syncing data between multiple devices is the biggest reason to use something like Firebase. That's one of its primary purposes. You would use Firebase for data storage instead of Core Data, and it would automatically handle syncing between devices. You don't write code to upload or download anything, you just read and write Firebase data and it handles the syncing. It supports user accounts, so if a user logs on on a different device, their data automatically syncs to that device. There are numerous other options besides Firebase, of course.

CloudKit also syncs between different devices, but it's linked to the current iCloud account on the phone. Since you want in-app login, it's not so good.